# Esper is throwing oom even after using ouput rate limiter

Tags: events, compression, out-of-memory, esper

We are creating an hourly context in esper and using @hint with output rate limiter.But we are still running out of memory in certain events.
XMX -12 G

In certain events, if we have bad compression, means, for example, we got data for 6 GB which is non-aggregated and therefore it turns out to be bad compression from esper.

I want to limit the size also on esper, so if we hit a limit before hourly context, I can flush this large chunk of data for which compression is bad.

Its like either you hit the hourly context or the size for flushing out of output data.

My esper query

```
 private static final String HOURLY_CONTEXT =
  "create context HourlyRollup start(0,*,*,*,*,0) end(59,*,*,*,*,59)";
  private static final String HINT = "@Hint('enable_outputlimit_opt') ";

private static final String HOURLY_STATEMENT = HINT+
      "context HourlyRollup "
          + "select count(*) as xcount,hourlyFloor(min(from_time)),a,b,c,d,e,f,"
          + "g,h,sum(h),sum(i),j,k,l,"
          + "m,n,y,o,p,q,r "
          + "from io.common.Bean where Dir in (-5,-3,0,1) "
          + "group by a,b,c,d,e,f,g,Direction,h,"
          + "i,j,k,l,m,l,n,o,p output all "+"when terminated";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your query is fully-aggregated otherwise Esper must retain the events since the select-clause is asking for event data. When the query is fully-aggregated Esper retainw only aggregated data and that is what you want.

This is not fully aggregated:

```
select a, b, count(*) from Event group by a
```

This is better and fully aggregated:

```
select a, b, count(*) from Event group by a, b
```

The doc for this is [here](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.3.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#processingmodel_aggregation_batch_group_agg).

Comment: Its a fully aggregated query..but still is retaining events